# How to write a comment header PHP file with Doxygen?

Tags: php, comments, doxygen

i trying to write a comment in each PHP file, then the comment will generated by Doxygen, does anyone know how to write a comment header PHP file?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a bit more?

Comment: i want to know how to write a documentation program using Doxygen, i start from the header of file, but i dont know how to write header file with correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your favorite $searchengine to look for "php doxygen tutorial". I found http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock to be helpful.

For PHP, you might also want to look into [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) or [docblox](http://www.docblox-project.org/).

Generally, a docblock header in a PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the file description
 *
 * @author Christian Weiske <cweiske@cweiske.de>
 */
...
```

I suggest reading the [phpDoc quickstart tutorial](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html). Note that doxygen supports the phpdoc syntax.

Comment: actually, i need a document with Doxygen, the @author, @file, @section has documented, but the files in the folder not documented, i'm getting stuck with this.

Comment: Ironically, this page is the first result for the query above :)

Comment: Same here, @AndréLaszlo. Google brought me here and this answer is sub-optimal.